# Kafka Connect Distributed Mode SSL Client Auth

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I’m trying to use `ssl.client.auth=required` within Kubernetes for some last mile protection.

This approach works fine for a single worker node, but when scaled up to multiple workers, SSL problems occur due to the workers not sending their own client certs between themselves.

Is this approach possible or will I need to take a different approach.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your full connect server properties. That property is for client auth, not communication between workers

Comment: Maybe this can just be handled with some network policies on the service.

Comment: Maybe, but can you still edit the question to include more information about your services?

Comment: What else do you want to see, there’s a trust and keystore configuration, and some sasl config.

Comment: Please show your entire k8s YAML definition for connect

Comment: And be sure to go over the docs https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/security.html#connect-security  (assuming you don't have something doing SSL termination within your k8s cluster)

Comment: A single worker is fine, the reverse proxy sends the client cert. The problem occurs when the workers need to talk to each other.

Comment: Okay. I'm not seeing an updated question with your configs to tell you what the problem is

Comment: The problem is the client auth, if I turn it off it works fine. The goal is to have ingress locked down through a reverse proxy with an API key, and client auth to avoid last mile attacks. My question is more how to make sure the workers can talk to each other. The only thing I can see is taking client auth out of the equation completely.